# Can I override a required error message from a member object?

Tags: c#, required

The base object has a required attribute of name as such:

```
public class member
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Now the parent member looks like:

```
public class parent
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The member is required")]
    public member mem{ get; set; }
}
```

The value of the parent is set in a dropdown list that sets both the name and the id of the member object. The member object is used in other locations where their error messages make sense, but in this instance, the user is selecting from a drop down that does not have a "name" field, so the error message is very confusing.

My question is, is there a way I can get the parent's error message to show rather than the member object's?

Comment: is introducing two subclasses a major issue?

Comment: @rene Perhaps. This project is nearly complete and low on time. I just came across this issue and was curious if anyone had a neat and easy trick. I rather not introduce too much new code.